# 20 комментариев к вопросу на ответе

Tags: дефект, локализация, тревоги, инструменты-модератора

В тексте тревоги Духа о 20+ комментариях у ответа написано "к этому вопросу". Вероятно, надо исправить. А если фраза общая для вопроса и ответа, то заменить на "к этому сообщению".

> Тревоги на ответе
>
> Более 20 комментариев к этому вопросу было опубликовано за прошедшие 3 дня

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 3):

Обновил переводы для группы строк:

- https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=posted%20in%20the%20past%20%5C%24commentDays%5C%24%20days%24

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.2.18.38600